# Getting text of nav items on clicking on them

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function

How can I get the text of a nav item when it's clicked and also the text should replace the previous text of nav item?
In javascript

Comment: What did you tried so far ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
$("#nav-id").click(function(){
  $(this).text("new text");
});
```